# display list group with json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to display my list of person with a json data structure like this

```
<pre>
   <ul class="list-group">
    <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">A</span>
    <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
      Jhon PAPOU
   </li>
   <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">B</span>
     <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
       Lionel Melin
    </li>
  <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">C</span>
  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    OSMEL GIBI
  </li>
  </ul>
    var jsonData = '[
     {"class":"A","name":"Jhon PAPOU","color":"rouge"},
     {"class":"B","name":"Lionel Melin","color":"vert"},
     {"class":"C","name":"Osmel GIBI","color":"jaune"},
    {"class":"D","name":"James DADIN","color":"noir"},
    ]';
```

I want to display my list with four small colored tiles at the bottom.

firstview[image]

[image: secondview]
I cannot reach my desired net display. Any ideas ?

Comment: can you please share JS code ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **map** function for your **jsonData** to manupulate into **HTML UI**. So without write css code to manage UI with help of **Bootstrap4 Classes**.
I hope below snippet will help you lot.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var jsonData = [
    {"class":"A","name":"Jhon PAPOU","color":"red"},
    {"class":"B","name":"Lionel Melin","color":"green"},
    {"class":"C","name":"Osmel GIBI","color":"blue"},
    {"class":"D","name":"James DADIN","color":"orange"},
  ];
  $('.list-group').after($('<div class="d-flex text-capitalize color-lebel"/>'));
  jsonData.map(function(k,v){
    $('.list-group').append('<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-start1 align-items-center">'+
      '<span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">'+k.class+'</span>'+
      '<span class="m-auto">'+k.name+'</span>'+
      '<span class="h-100 d-block position-absolute" style="background:'+k.color+'; width:5px; right:0; top:0;"></span>'+
      '</li>');
    $('.color-lebel').append('<div class="d-inline-block mr-2 my-2"><span class="badge" style="background:'+k.color+'">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span> '+k.color+'</div>');
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container my-3">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <ul class="list-group"></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop the jsonData and use its values in it. you could use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) or [for-of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)
If there is some other issue then please specify it

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below code to create html

```html
<body  id="banner">    
<ul id="mylists">
</ul> 
</div>
<style>
.list-group-item {
padding: 8px;
list-style: none;
border: solid 1px #eee;
width: 300px;
border-right-width: 5px;
}

.badge {
padding: 3px 10px;
background: #eee;
}
.rouge {
border-right-color: red;
}
.vert {
border-right-color: yellow;
}
.jaune {
border-right-color: green;
}
.noir {
border-right-color: blue;
}
span.name-span {margin-left: 10px;}
</style>
</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jsonData = [
{"class":"A","name":"Jhon PAPOU","color":"rouge"},
{"class":"B","name":"Lionel Melin","color":"vert"},
{"class":"C","name":"Osmel GIBI","color":"jaune"},
{"class":"D","name":"James DADIN","color":"noir"}
];
jQuery(document).ready(function($){  
 $.each(jsonData, function(key,value) {
  var html = '';    
  html+='<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center '+value.color+'" style="border-right-color:'+value.color+';">';
  html+='<span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">'+value.class+'</span>';
  html+='<span class="name-span">'+value.name+'</span>';
  html+='</li>';
  $("#mylists").append(html);
 }); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.name-span {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.list-group-item {
  position: relative;
}

.color-span {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 60%;
  transform: tranlateX(-50%);
  width: 20px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="banner">
  <ul id="mylists">
  </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var jsonData = [{
      "class": "A",
      "name": "Jhon PAPOU",
      "color": "red"
    },
    {
      "class": "B",
      "name": "Lionel Melin",
      "color": "blue"
    },
    {
      "class": "C",
      "name": "Osmel GIBI",
      "color": "green"
    },
    {
      "class": "D",
      "name": "James DADIN",
      "color": "yellow"
    }
  ];
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $.each(jsonData, function(key, value) {
      var html = '';
      html += '<li class="list-group-item d-flex align-items-center">';
      html += '<span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">' + value.class + '</span>';
      html += '<span class="name-span">' + value.name + '</span>'
      html += '<span class="color-span" style="background-color:' + value.color + '"></span>';
      html += '</li>';
      $("#mylists").append(html);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code snippet (please ignore styling as original classes are not known).

Here you can iterate over json data and create required html and while iterating save color codes in an array and later use it for legends.
make sure that you move span inside li instead of outside it

```js
$(function(){
  var jsonData = [
     {"class":"A","name":"Jhon PAPOU","color":"red"},
     {"class":"B","name":"Lionel Melin","color":"green"},
     {"class":"C","name":"Osmel GIBI","color":"blue"},
    {"class":"D","name":"James DADIN","color":"orange"},
    ];
   
    var colors = [];
    var $ul = $('#list-group');
    $.each(jsonData, function(key, value){
        var html = '<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"><span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">' + value.class + '</span>' + value.name + '<span style="background-color:' + value.color + ';">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></li>';
        $ul.append(html);
        if(colors.indexOf(value.color)==-1) {
           colors.push(value.color);
        }
    });
    
    var colorHTML = '';
    $.each(colors, function(index, value){
    //console.log(value);
       colorHTML += '<span style="background-color:' + value + ';">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;<span>' + value +'</span>&nbsp;';
    });
    //console.log(colorHTML);
    $ul.after(colorHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-group" id="list-group"></ul>
```